# Create a batch file to generate Unity executable

Tags: batch-file, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to understand how Unity works, so I started to create simple scene in which I move a "player" in a 3D scenario that I create with Sketchup. Now I'm interested to automatize this process: I will create a simple batch file (for Windows or for OS X or for Linux) in which I just give in input the path to the folder in which is stored my 3D model and by pressing a button it generate an executable Unity file, that I can run on every device who can use Unity.
Can anyone help me? I took a look about the [Unity doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html), but I'm not sure if i did well or not.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a executable Unity file? Do you want to create a build for iOS or Android or PC? Or do you want to create a Unity project file?

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to do this.  (But it might be possible with replacing a recourse; not sure)

Comment: @marsh: sorry for delay of my answer. Also I'm trying to create an executable to create automatically a Unity file to play it on several devices. I thought it should work so: 1. Ask to the user for the path of a 3D model (.fbx or .obj) 2. Ask on which device the user will play the Unity executable 3. Generate the binary. I hope that you can understand what I mean otherwise just ask me